# $L^2$ is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, fourier-series

I have to see that $L^2$ is a vector space, and would like to verify what I did. I excuse the long mail, but I am self-studying this, and is possible that I made wrong interpretations of what I am supposed to check.

I noticed that to check commutativity ($f + g = g + f$) or the existence of an additive inverse, I should know that if $f, g$ are square integrable, then the sum is also square integrable. And similarily, $-f$ is square integrable. 
So these two things would be a consequence of showing that, for $\alpha$ a scalar and $f,g$ square integrable, then $(\alpha f)(x) + g(x)$ is also square integrable, i.e  $\int_a^b |[(\alpha f)(x) + g(x)]|^2 dx. $
By, https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/square-integrable-functions-as-a-vector-space.814979/ , I could prove that 
$$ \int_a^b |[(\alpha f)(x) + g(x)]|^2 dx \leq |\alpha|^2 \int^{a}_{b} | f(x) |^2 dx + \int^{a}_{b} | g(x) |^2 dx + 2\ | \overline{\alpha}|  \sqrt{ \int^{a}_{b} |f(x)|^{2} dx \int^{a}_{b} |g(x)|^{2} dx},$$ where the first two terms are square integrable, and the third term... depends on two square integrable functions, but I'm not sure how I can say that it is a square int term. Are products of square ints square ints, and the square root of that is also square int?

Now, to check $L^2$ is a vector space, let $f,g,h$ square integrable functions in $[a,b]$:

$1) f + g $ is square int, i.e. $  \int_a^b |[(f + g)(x)]|^2 dx $ = $  \int_a^b |[(f)(x) + g(x)]|^2 dx$ = $  \int_a^b |[g(x) + f(x)]|^2 dx$ =  $  \int_a^b |[(g + f)(x)]|^2 dx ,$ by definition of sum of functions and as they are evaluated in a field, the sum is commutative.

2) Because of associativity in the field $  \int_a^b |[(f + g)(x)+ h(x)]|^2 dx $ = $  \int_a^b |[f(x) + (g+ h)(x)]|^2 dx $ so, $(f + g) + h = f + (g +h)$ is in $L^2 .$

3) If $n(x) = 0$ is the additive identity, then $  \int_a^b |[f(x)+ n(x)]|^2 dx $ = $  \int_a^b |[f(x)+ 0]|^2 dx $ = $  \int_a^b |[f(x)]|^2 dx $ for every $f \in L^2.$

4) If $-f(x)$ is the additive inverse for $f$, then $f + (-f)$ is square integrable, and $  \int_a^b |[f(x) -f(x)]|^2 dx $ = $  \int_a^b |0| dx $ = $0$ for every $f \in L^2.$

5)  $ \int_a^b | \alpha( \beta f(x))|^2 dx $ =  $ ( \int_a^b |(\alpha\beta)f(x)|^2 dx), $ by properties of the field .

6) If $g(x) =1$ is the multiplicative identity, then  $ \int_a^b |g(x) f(x)|^2 dx $  =  $ \int_a^b |1 f(x)|^2 dx $  = $ \int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx $ for every $f \in L^2.$

7) If $(f + h) (x)$ is square int, them $ \int_a^b |\beta (f + h) (x)|^2 dx = \int_a^b |(\beta f)(x) + (\beta h)(x)|^2 dx ,$ so equality holds and $(\beta f)(x) + (\beta h)(x)$is square integrable.

8) As $f$ is square integrable, then $(\alpha + \beta)f$ is square integrable, e.g. $ \int_a^b |[(\alpha + \beta )f] (x)|^2 dx$ = $ \int_a^b |\alpha f (x)  + \beta f (x)|^2 dx,$ by field properties. So equality holds and $\alpha f (x)  + \beta f (x)$ is square integrable.

Comment: You sound a little confused about square integrability, for instance in the paragraph after your first inequality.  A *function* of $x$ is square- integrable: you want to show that the integrand in the LHS is square-integrable, by bounding the integral of its square (i.e. the LHS).  You bound it by a finite real number, and that's all the RHS needs to be: it's a number, not a function — its job is not to be square-integrable or otherwise, so asking whether a square root is integrable makes little sense.  It just needs to be finite and correctly bound the LHS.

Comment: Ok, so for conmutativity for example, I would also have to bound the sum for a finite real number, etc etc, i didn't understand what Supposed to check, as i said it could be

Comment: For commutativity you only need to check that $f+g = g+f$.  But before you can talk about commutativity you may need to establish that $f+g$ makes sense (is well-defined), which is why it must be shown (if it hasn't already) that $f+g \in L^2$.  Once you've done that there's no need to repeat it for $g+f$ or for $(f+g)+h$, etc.

Comment: There is a separate minor subtlety here in that in many contexts $L^2$ is defined as *equivalence* classes of functions (up to almost-everywhere equality), and then part of well-definedness is showing that the equivalence class of $f+g$ is independent of the choice of representatives for $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But one more question: if i  show that $f+g \in L^2$ Then It makes sense to me the argument I gave in 1) for conmutativity, is it really correct?

Comment: For 1), the argument you give is insufficient in some sense (or you could say it misses the point).  It's not enough that $f+g$ and $g+f$ have the same norm: they must be the same element of $L^2$, meaning they are exactly the same function (up to equivalence).  This is a stronger claim than what you proved, although you used it implicitly as part of your computation.